# Generate a Column with random Percentage that sum to one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a random percentage column where it should sum up to 1

Current Table :

```
Col1    Value
A        100
B        100
```

Wanted Example 1 : if there are two rows, then the random value can be any number,but the total has to be 1

```
Col1    Value  Random  New Value
A        100    0.7    70
B        100    0.3    30
                 1
```

Wanted Example 2 :  three rows samples

```
Col1    Value  Random  New Value
A        100    0.2     20
B        100    0.1     10
C        100    0.7     70
                 1
```

Comment: the first table has different values (100,1000) the next two tables have the same values (100). will the values vary or be the same?

Comment: thank for reply Sammy, yes you are right, it should be 100, i have revised it. thanks

Comment: You can do: `df['Random'] = df['Value']/df['Value'].sum()`

Comment: You could add the round function to get two significant figures for odd numbers

Comment: thank Sammy, i have revised the case where i want the random no. not averagely distributed.

Comment: 'random value should be 0.5' and 'random value should be 0.33', how is it random then?

Comment: yeah, foy, I think you should edit your post, to make it clearer.

Comment: yes, create a column with random percentage, however, the total amount of that column has to be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.dirichlet`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html) and [`np.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': list("ABC"), 'Value': [100]*3})
df['random'] = np.around(np.random.dirichlet
                        (np.ones(df.shape[0]),size=1)[0],
                         decimals = 1)
df['New value'] = (df['Value']*df['random']).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Value  random  New value
0    A    100     0.4         40
1    B    100     0.3         30
2    C    100     0.3         30
```

Comment: Nope, `df.ndim` returns how many dimension it has, which would be `2`.

Comment: thank sammy, i tried your code and some way it works, but the problem is that the around(decimals= 8 ) , otherwise the column sum is 0 again, i think it is due to too many rows, are there any intelligent way to detect how much decimals i need ?

Comment: To avoid that, I don't think you can do any better than @amanb's comment on your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `numpy` function `random.randint`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [100, 100, 100]})

nums = np.random.randint(10, size=len(df))
df['Random'] = nums / nums.sum()
df['New'] = df['Value'] * df['Random']

df.loc['Sum', :] = df.sum()
```

Output:

```
     Value  Random     New
0    100.0  0.1250   12.50
1    100.0  0.3125   31.25
2    100.0  0.5625   56.25
Sum  300.0  1.0000  100.00
```

Comment: `df.loc['Sum', :] = df.sum()` should be `df['Sum'] = df.sum()`

Comment: @jezrael It's correct. I wanted to show the sum per each column.